# What would be the best way of getting the child "info" without the parent key?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image: database]

I want to get only the "info" here. what would be the best way of getting so?

Comment: DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Pairs").child("Name+Name").child("Info"); That should get you just the info from the "Info" node. There really isn't a way to bypass parent nodes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Firebase Realtime Database always returns full nodes in its result. There is no way to only read the `Info` child of each node in this data structure. If you want that, you should store the `Info` for each pair in a separate top-level node, like:

```
Breedings
  Name+Name
    ...
  NameES+NameEE
    ...
Infos
  Name+Name
    assigningDate: ...
    fatherPGN: ...
    motherPGN: ...
  NameES+NameEE
    assigningDate: ...
    fatherPGN: ...
    motherPGN: ...
```

With your current structure the best you can do is to read all data, and only process the `Info` for each child node. To do that you'd use something like:

```
DatabaseReference pairsRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Pairs");
pairsRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot pairSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            DataSnapshot infoSnapshot = pairSnapshot.child("Info");

            Log.i("PAIRS", pairSnapshot.getKey());
            Log.i("PAIRS", infoSnapshot.child("assigningDate").getValue(String.class));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        throw databaseError.toException();
    }
}
```

Note that there have been quite a few [questions about this topic](https://www.google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com+firebase+android+without+parent+key) before, so I recommend looking at those too.